# Analogue Expedited App Review for WP-application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, marketplace

As far as I know the certification process in the Windows Phone Store lasts from 5 to 9 days (mean 7). My application is confined to a specific date of the company, and there is a suspicion that the application does not have time to appear in the store by that date. But I would like to make it. In AppStore there is such thing as a Request for an Expedited app Review. You must fill out a form, submit your app, specify the reason for the request and a description (Time-Sensitive Event in this case), and in most cases, Apple makes a decision on the application within 2 days (or so). Of course there are restrictions on the use of this possibility (1 per year for an account.)

Actually the question. Is it possible to speed up the certification process for Windows Phone applications? Or at least reduce to a minimum the time of certification.

I would be grateful for related links, or any other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provision of publishing app immediately as per users request. Windows phone marketplace does not allow user to publish there app without going through certification process and no one can manually publish app even you contact microsoft support.